# Sort List objects based on object data type

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, comparator

I have List of LabResults objects, i wanted to sort based on list object data,here is my collection

```
public class LabResult implements Serializable{

private String id;
private String name;
private String unit;
private String abnormal;  //Contains String either "A" or "N"

}
private List<LabResult> mLabResults;
```

I want to sort the list to show abnormal = "A" on top of list view and rest under that 
can any one suggest me how to do that in java/android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a comparator

```
public class LabResultComparator implements Comparator<LabResult> {
    public int compare(LabResult p1, LabResult p2) {
        return p1.abnormal.compareTo(p2.abnormal);
    }
}
```

compareTo retuns 0 if the two strings are equal, a value less than 0 if  p1.abnormal is greater than p2.abnormal, and the other way around.

Comment: And you can use it like `Collections.sort(mLabResults, new LabResultComparator());`